# Failed to map a flink MapFunction and get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, generics, apache-flink

I'm learning Flink and trying to integrate it into my project. However, thing doesn't go well. When I begin to test my code, I get an exception which was shown below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoFromInputs(TypeExtractor.java:991)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoWithTypeHierarchy(TypeExtractor.java:913)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateCreateTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:848)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(TypeExtractor.java:617)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getMapReturnTypes(TypeExtractor.java:169)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.map(DataStream.java:528)
at com.angho.cloud.flink.executor.AbstractFlinkExecutor.execute(AbstractFlinkExecutor.java:29)
at com.angho.cloud.flink.config.FlinkExecutorInitializer.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(FlinkExecutorInitializer.java:77)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:676)
at com.angho.cloud.flink.config.FlinkExecutorInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlinkExecutorInitializer.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 39 more
```

Here's the code:

```
package com.angho.cloud.flink.executor;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.core.FlinkEnvFactory;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.sink.FlinkSinkInvoker;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Description:flink-executor
 *
 * @author guobin On date 2018/4/8.
 * @version 1.0
 * @param I input data type
 * @param O output data type
 */
public abstract class AbstractFlinkExecutor<I, O> implements FlinkExecutable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractFlinkExecutor.class);

    private FlinkEnvFactory envFactory;

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = this.envFactory.createEnv();

        DataStream<I> sourceStream = env.addSource(this.source());

        sourceStream.map(this::transform)
                .addSink(this.sinkFunction());

        try {
            env.execute(this.jobName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Failed to execute the job:" + this.jobName(), ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * defined the datasource
     * @return datasource function
     */
    protected abstract SourceFunction<I> source();

    /**
     * data-transformation
     * @param src input data
     * @return transformed output data
     */
    protected abstract O transform(I src);

    /**
     * sink action
     * @param o the data need sinking
     */
    protected abstract void sink(O o);

    /**
     * the name of the job
     * @return job's name
     */
    protected abstract String jobName();

    /**
     * define a sink function
     * @return sink function
     */
    private FlinkSinkInvoker<O> sinkFunction() {
        return new FlinkSinkInvoker<>(this::sink);
    }

    public void setEnvFactory(FlinkEnvFactory envFactory) {
        this.envFactory = envFactory;
    }
}
```

I've just debugged my program, and I suspect that the generics might be the culprit. But I have no idea how to solve this problem and make my program work.

Could you please give me a hand?

More code has been shown as below.

```
package com.angho.cloud.flink.executor;

import com.angho.cloud.flink.exception.AnghoFlinkException;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.config.DefaultKafkaConf;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.core.StringFlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * Description: flink-kafka
 *
 * @author guobin On date 2018/4/8.
 * @version 1.0
 */
public abstract class BaseKafkaFlinkExecutor<T> extends AbstractFlinkExecutor<String, T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1060498807469877345L;

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BaseKafkaFlinkExecutor.class);

    private DefaultKafkaConf kafkaConf;

    @Override
    protected SourceFunction<String> source() {
        if (Objects.isNull(this.kafkaConf)) {
            LOG.error("Kafka configuration hasn't been set up yet.");
            throw new AnghoFlinkException("No kafka configuration for:" + this.getClass().getName());
        }
        final StringFlinkKafkaConsumer consumer = new StringFlinkKafkaConsumer(this.topic(), this.kafkaConf.getProperties());
        this.setUpOffsetOperation(consumer);

        return consumer;
    }

    /**
     * the topic of kafka
     * @return kafka-topic
     */
    protected abstract String topic();

    /**
     * the kafka offset behavior
     */
    protected void setUpOffsetOperation(StringFlinkKafkaConsumer consumer) {
        consumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets();
    }

    public void setKafkaConf(DefaultKafkaConf kafkaConf) {
        this.kafkaConf = kafkaConf;
    }
}
```

The final subclass is:

```
package com.angho.cloud.consumer;

import com.angho.cloud.flink.annotation.FlinkExecutor;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.config.FlinkExecutorType;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.core.StringFlinkKafkaConsumer;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.exception.AnghoFlinkException;
import com.angho.cloud.flink.executor.BaseKafkaFlinkExecutor;
import com.angho.cloud.item.TestItem;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Description:the flink-kafka example
 *
 * @author guobin On date 2018/4/13.
 * @version 1.0
 */
@FlinkExecutor(type = FlinkExecutorType.KAFKA)
public class KafkaFlinkExample extends BaseKafkaFlinkExecutor<TestItem> {

    private static final Map<String, TestItem> MAP = new HashMap<>(16);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6795242068228230304L;

    @Override
    protected String topic() {
        return "num-test";
    }

    @Override
    protected TestItem transform(String src) {
        String[] arr = src.split(" ");
        String key = arr[0];
        Integer value = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        TestItem item = Optional.ofNullable(MAP.get(key)).orElseGet(TestItem::new);
        item.setKey(key);
        item.setValue(item.getValue() + value);

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    protected void sink(TestItem testItem) {
        MAP.put(testItem.getKey(), testItem);
        System.out.println(testItem);
    }

    @Override
    protected String jobName() {
        return "kafka-flink-example";
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUpOffsetOperation(StringFlinkKafkaConsumer consumer) {
        consumer.setStartFromLatest();
    }
}
```

I invoke the execute() to start my program. The KafkaFlinkExample shows that the I is String.class and The O is TestItem.class. TestItem is POJO:

```
package com.angho.cloud.item;

/**
 * Description:
 *
 * @author guobin On date 2018/4/13.
 * @version 1.0
 * @since jdk 1.8
 */
public class TestItem {

    private String key;

    private int value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestItem{" +
                "key='" + key + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I wish the code I've added to my question may help to express myself.
Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have a concrete run of this code ? What is passed to `I` and `O` ? Which instruction is causing the error ?

Comment: Hi, I've just update my code.@YassineBadache

Comment: This may be due to the usage of method references. try replacing it with an anonymous inner class.

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler I've tried the anonymous inner class just now. It's a pity that it still doesn't  work. The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 disappeared but new exception came out-------Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Type of TypeVariable 'T' in 'class com.angho.cloud.flink.executor.AbstractFlinkExecutor' could not be determined. This is most likely a type erasure problem. The type extraction currently supports types with generic variables only in cases where all variables in the return type can be deduced from the input type(s).